# Customize Grails create-app

Tags: grails, gsp

I want my Grails Apps to have a different Look&Feel than the standard Grails one. As I didn't want to modify every single application, I would like to customize the project creation (`grails create-app`)

After googling a bit around I found the possibility to modify the templates directly in the GRAILS_HOME directory. (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/create-app-customization-td1351040.html)

So I modified `GRAILS_HOME/src/grails/grails-app/views/main.gsp` and `GRAILS_HOME/src/war/css/main.css` but nothing changed when creating a new grails app. I rebuild the whole GRAILS_HOME project via `./gradlew assemble` nothing changed. What have I missed?
The jar file at `GRAILS_HOME/dist/grails-resources-1.3.7.jar` contains the updated files.

Answer (score 2):

This is better to do by implementing your own plugin for grails, that will replace all required files (`main.gsp`, `main.css`) after installing.

Comment: I want to use the same main.gsp, main.css etc. for all my apps. Writing a plugin seems to be more costly in the first place.

Comment: making and maintaining your own version of grails framework seem to be much more costly :)

Comment: Not convinced. With a company specific grails version everybody has to dowload one file. Otherwise I have to write the plugin, tell everybody to not only download grails, but also the plugin. With every change in the grails plugin API you have to communicate which version of Grails to use with which version of your internal plugin. And you have to manually add the plugin to every single app, which you can do either manually or by script where you are at the beginning: an own customized grails version. And well, we are not talking about huge code modifications but a few layout files.

Comment: I agree with @splix. If you have your layout files a plugin, you can replace those files by updating your plugin. If you modify the Grails core, you have to run create-app and make new apps, where you would copy your layouts from. Keep your plugin in a local repository, and you're set to go.

Answer (score 0):

We came across the same issue where files changed in the grails directory were not seen when we did a create-app. We came to the realization that what we really wanted was a way to quickly create an application with our customizations. Not that we need grails to create that app. Our solution was to create a skeleton application with the desired customizations and jar up the application directory. When we want to create a new app,

- grails create-app foo
- cp /custom-grails-app.jar .
- jar xf custom-grails-app.jar
- vi application.properties      <-- change application name to "foo"

And now we have an application with the desired structure. Not the most elegant approach. But it works! ;)